# Correct selector specification for element.closest() DOM method

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to get hold of the outer div's *id* from the innermost button element in the following HTML:

```
    <div id="menu_level_0" class="menu_level">
        <div class="editor">
            <div class="ui_details">
                <div class="dialog_buttons">
                    <button class="ui_btn" type="button">OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Dumping *e.target* from the button's event handler callback fn to the console returns the correct button element.

But why does calling

```
e.target.closest(".menu_level");
```

from the same callback give me *null*?

Comment: It might help if you include your entire event handler callback and create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in which we can run your code.

Comment: guess your mark up is not what you think it is...

Comment: Temporary! 
https://jsfiddle.net/rcfop9mv/
In this jsfiddle it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `console.log` your `e.target`. It's probably another element, not your button.

```js
// proof that, button.closest() works:
console.log(document.querySelector("button").closest('.menu_level'))
```

```html
<div id="menu_level_0" class="menu_level">
    <div class="editor">
        <div class="ui_details">
            <div class="dialog_buttons">
                <!-- this in onclick="" is the button element -->
                <button class="ui_btn" type="button" onclick="console.log(this.closest('.menu_level'))">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```